# ByVal DataTable Manipulation

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I think I'm missing something fundamental about how DataTables work. The following procedure starts with `GetData`, bringing in `what` as a filled DataTable. All the following code does is pass through copies of the datatable, manipulate it, then return it:

```
Sub GetData(ByVal what As DataTable)
    Dim Part As DataTable = Generate(what)
End Sub


Function Generate(ByVal brown As DataTable)
    Dim lameface As DataTable = DoStuff(brown)

    Return lameface
End Function


Function DoStuff(ByVal cow As DataTable)
    Dim result As DataTable = cow

    result.Rows.RemoveAt(0)

    Return result
End Function
```

The way this is written above, function `DoStuff` will remove the top row from `result` *and* `cow`. Similarly, `brown` and `what` will also have that first row removed, even though they are sent as `ByVal`.

If I change the first line in `DoStuff` from

```
Dim result As DataTable = cow
```

to

```
Dim result As DataTable = cow.copy
```

then `cow`, `brown` and `what` are left alone. Why is this? Marking a parameter as `ByVal` is supposed to send a *copy* of the object instead of the original, so why do I have tell it to use a copy when instantiating `result`? If I do a similar procedure using integers instead of datatables, it works as I would expect. What am I missing about datatables?

I poked around on MSDN's articles for datatables and didn't see anything that spoke to this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `DataTable` is a reference type, therefore you don't have copies of the table but just of it's reference. So if you modify it you will modify the original table.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0bdca4.aspx (applies to VB.NET as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ByVal` keyword doesn't necessarily indicate that a copy of the value is passed to the method.  If the parameter is a reference type, like a `DataTable`, then a copy of the pointer is passed to the method - it still references the same object, so any changes made to the object in the method will be maintained once the method completes execution.

The `ByRef` keyword would permit the method to *change* the object the variable is pointing to, or the actual value if the parameter is a simple type (like `int`).

In your situation above, if you want to remove a row inside `DoStuff`, but not affect the source `DataTable`, then you need to make a copy of the `DataTable` before doing the remove operation.

Comment: That makes sense. However, the MSDN article on Value & Reference Types (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs(v=vs.90).aspx) says strings are reference types. When I try this procedure using a string (instead of a datatable), it works the same way an integer does. Why is that?

Comment: Apparently strings are a special case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876309/reference-types-behaves-like-value-type-in-vb-net

Comment: For any future viewers, this post was also helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707622/byval-and-byref-with-reference-type