# Reference Type and Value Type in Memory

Tags: c#, oop

If i have a class `Person` and this class have data members as `FirstName`, `LastName`.

```
 public Class Person
 {
     public string firstName {get; set;}
     public string lastName   {get; set;}

 }
```

Class `Person` is a Reference Type but `firstName` and `lastName` are Value Type. Then how this would be stored? Would Class `Person` be stored on Heap and `firstName` and `lastName` would be stored on stack? Can someone please help me understand how this works exactly?

Comment: its all on the heap. Google would be a better resource than SO for this kind of question.

Comment: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)'s some good reading on the subject of value types. The most important point, I feel, is C# works hard to make it irrelevant - you don't have to care about stack vs heap.

Comment: Also, `string` is a [reference type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069155/is-string-a-value-type-or-a-reference-type).

Comment: by the way string  is immutable reference-types. It is very important the word !!!immutable!!!

Answer (score 3):

In this case, everything will be stored on the heap, because everything is **contained** within a reference type.

Note also that `string` is a reference type anyway (although MS does everything to make it look like a value type).

Comment: if the Person class is created in the main(Progam.cs) the referance of this class will be added to the Sack and not heap.