# Example of practical of "ref" use

Tags: c#, ref

I am struggling how to use "ref" (to pass argument by reference) in real app. I would like to have simple and mainly meaningful example. Everything I found so far could be easily redone with adding return type to the method.
Any idea someone?
Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best example coming in my mind is a function to Swap two variables values:

```
static void Swap<T>(ref T el1, ref T el2)
{
    var mem = el1;
    el1 = el2;
    el2 = mem;
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string a = "Hello";
    string b = "Hi";

    Swap(ref a, ref b);
    // now a = "Hi" b = "Hello"

    // it works also with array values:
    int[] arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    Swap(ref arr[0], ref arr[2]);
    // now arr = {3,2,1}
}
```

A function like this one, cannot be done without the `ref` keyword.

Comment: Excellent! Now I doubt I will be ever good programmer, this would never come to my mind.

Comment: @Loj: More than anything, I think what you should have learned from the answers to this question is that it's quite rare you'll have a use for the `ref` keyword. The fact that you couldn't think of it is no indication you're a bad programmer.

Comment: @Loj: yes, Cody is right. I've used ref keyword more than rarely. I thought to the Swap function because is just the ref example I always remember (don't know why)

Comment: I think its really nice example as even for non generic types it makes the swapping elegant and easy.

Comment: I would be careful about this Swap as swapping a custom class that contains a string which the string will be swapped you don't need the REF because it's already a reference and only the data of the reference will be changed.  When you pass the string you are trying to swap the reference itself.  A good reference for that is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096449/c-sharp-string-reference-type

So in a sense I disagreed with the assumption that this function cannot be done without the ref keyboard.  Just put your string in a class.

Comment: @MarcRoussel: I think you should carefully re-read the best answer to that question, because IMO you're confusing "reference type" with the way of passing arguments "by reference" or "by value"...

Comment: @digEmAll No I was just saying that it can be done without ref.  Sorry for any misunderstanding.  By the way the answer is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 5):

One possibly corner-case example: [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z791w8a.aspx). Without passing the variable by reference, there's no way of performing the increment atomically.

I can't say I've used `ref` very much myself, to be honest - I generally steer clear of the need to return multiple values, and even then `out` is *usually* sufficient. Many of the cases where I've *seen* `ref` used, it's been due to the author not understanding how arguments are passed in .NET when it comes to reference types.

Comment: I am thining of using for value types of course

Comment: @Loj: I don't think there needs to be any "of course" about it - `ref` is still potentially useful for reference types, if you want the caller's argument expression to refer to a different object after the call.

Comment: "Many of the cases where I've seen ref used, it's been due to the author not understanding how arguments are passed in .NET when it comes to reference types." Very True Jon!!!

Answer (score 4):

The `TryParse` methods built into the framework are typical examples. They use `out` instead of `ref` but it is the same semantics, it's just that the caller doesn't need to initialize the value. Example:

```
int result;
bool isSuccess = int.TryParse("some string", out result);
if (isSuccess)
{
    // use the result here
}
```

As you can see the function returns a boolean indicating whether the operation succeeds but the actual result is returned as `out` parameter.

Comment: Yep but I mean specifically ref in any practical example :) I thought it is simple but still cannot think any example.

Comment: @Loj, ref is useful when you want to modify a value type inside a method.

Comment: I know, but could you give me practical example?

Comment: @Loj: I use `TryParse` all the time, and occasionally similar helper functions like it. How is it impractical?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Main(string args[])
{
    int i=0;
    AddSomething(ref i);
    AddSomething(ref i);
    AddSomething(ref i);
    AddSomething(ref i);


    string mystr = "Hello";
    AddSomeText(ref mystr);
    Console.WriteLine(mystr);


    Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", i);
}


public static void AddSomeText(ref string str)
{
    str+= " World!";
}


public static void AddSomething(ref int ii)
{
    ii+=1;
}
```

Comment: If `TryParse` isn't practical, this *certainly* isn't. In fact, if I saw code like this in an app I was tasked to maintain, I'd probably recoil in horror.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a _meaningful_ example, which is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common places I see it, is in Save methods of some frameworks.

The reason is that in many cases it is not actually possible to maintain the same object over a save call, if the object is being serialized to another machine and then comes back as a new instance (perhaps with some extra defaults). In that case you need the ref to make it obvious that the original reference is no longer valid.

As for its NECESSITY, I can't come up with an example where it would be required. Most places out is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good example would be trampolining.

This is where you take a recursive function and rework it to a method that is repeatidly called on a set of values. The reason being that instead of going into the stack very deeply the stack remains flat because you return after every call instead of calling yourself.

Regards GJ