# My subroutine won't call on the values I need

Tags: c#, console-application, subroutine

I got 2 subroutines which make it so that they ask two different players for a name, but when I call on it in the main, it says a argument1 must be passed with a 'ref' keyword, but am I not doing that already?

```
static string GetPlayer1(ref string name1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("PlayerX enter your name:");
    name1 = Console.ReadLine();
    return name1;
}

static string GetPlayer2(ref string name2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("PlayerO enter your name:");
    name2 = Console.ReadLine();
    return name2;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name1 = GetPlayer1(name1);
    string name2 = GetPlayer2(name2); 
...
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to pass parameters to those methods at all?

Comment: did you down vote both of the correct asnwers given to you?

Comment: @SimonPrice: He didn't because he can't.

Answer (score 4):

Here the `ref` in the method parameters is unneeded, in fact you *don't even need parameters at all*. Change it to this:

```
static string GetPlayer1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("PlayerX enter your name:");
    return Console.ReadLine();
}

static string GetPlayer2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("PlayerO enter your name:");
    return Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name1 = GetPlayer1();
    string name2 = GetPlayer2();
}
```

However if it was your *intention* to use `ref` (as an example or an exercise), then this would be how to do it. The methods now do not have a return type (`void` instead of `string`) because the texts are returned by means of assignment to the `ref` parameters.

```
static void GetPlayer1(ref string name1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("PlayerX enter your name:");
    name1 = Console.ReadLine();
}

static void GetPlayer2(ref string name2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("PlayerO enter your name:");
    name2 = Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name1;
    string name2;
    GetPlayer1(ref name1);  // "ref" must now be specified, simply because
    GetPlayer2(ref name2);  // both methods also specify it.
}
```

For more about `ref` (e.g. when or how to use it), see these questions:
- [Example of practical of "ref" use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646159/example-of-practical-of-ref-use)
- [Why use the 'ref' keyword when passing an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186891/why-use-the-ref-keyword-when-passing-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are not doing that:

```
    string name1 = GetPlayer1(ref name1);
    string name2 = GetPlayer2(ref name2);
```

What you did is to add the ref keyword to your method definition (creating a ref *parameter*). You have to use it also in your method call (creating a ref *argument*).

In your current case though there is no need to pass the arguments by ref. You are setting them with the return value of your `GetName`method.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you define a method with a **ref** parameter, you need to call that method with the parameter as reference:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name1 = GetPlayer1(ref name1);
    string name2 = GetPlayer2(ref name2);
}
```

And just for completeness, as the other answers already tell you: I don't see the necessity for reference-calling here, you can accomplish your goals without it.