# CMap in c# with 4 parameters

Tags: c#, mfc

I'm porting a c++ MFC class in c# and i have a problem.

The c++ class have a

```
CMap<int,int,CString,CString>MapIndexNote;
```

How can i create the equivalent in c#  ? I have read about Dictionnary and Hastables, but i have difficulty with 4 parameters.

Thanks a lot,

Nixeus

Comment: `Dictionary<int, string>` ?!

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent is `Dictionary<int, string>`.

Looking at [the definition of CMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s897094z(v=vs.80).aspx) you can see that the 2nd and 4th types only exist to let you specify whether the 1st and 3rd types are passed by reference or by value.

C# will do the right thing semi-automatically: because all value types including `int` are passed by value, whereas reference types including `string` are passed as (reference-counted) references (however note that [a 'reference' doesn't mean the same thing in C# as in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1096449/49942)).

Comment: .NET *doesn't* use reference counting. With both value types and reference types, the value of the expression is passed by value by default. There's no need to make a distinction for argument passing - but it *is* worth noting that the value of an expression is never an object, only a value type value or a reference. (Or a pointer, of course...)

Comment: I should have said "garbage collectable" and not "reference counted".