# Why is it only showing a blank? Why wont it parse correctly?

Tags: c#, parsing, interpreter, visual-c#-express-2010

I am trying to make a Parser and Interpreter or Compiler.
Right now when I try to execute the test code all it shows is blank.
Am I not parsing it or is something interfering or what?
Can someone take a look and tell me whats not working?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace Mikebite
{
     class Program
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string code = "";
                compile("function Main {", code);
                compile("x = Hello world!!", code);
                compile("print x", code);
                compile("input x", code);
                compile("} ;", code);

                Console.WriteLine(code);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        static void compile(string line, string code)
        {
            string[] tokens = line.Split(' ');

            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
            {
                if (tokens[i].Contains("function"))
                {
                    code += ":" + tokens[i+1];
                    i++;
                }
                else if (tokens[i].Contains("="))
                {
                    code += "PUSH " + tokens[i-1] + "\n";
                    code += "PUSH " + tokens[i+1] + "\n";
                    code += "SET\n";
                    i++;
                }
                else if (tokens[i].Contains("exec"))
                {
                    code += "GOTO " + tokens[i+1] + "\n";
                    i++;
                }
                else if (tokens[i].Contains("}"))
                {
                    code += "RTN\n";
                }
                else if (tokens[i].Contains("input"))
                {
                    code += "PUSH " + tokens[i+1] + "\nPUSH NULL\nINPUT\n";
                }
                else if (tokens[i].Contains("print"))
                {
                    code += "PUSH " + tokens[i+1] + "\nPUSH NULL\nPRINT\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static void compile(string line, string code)`

You're passing code in as a string, but not requesting it to return with any data, yet your usage of the function clearly states that you're trying to alter it with each call. Change the call to a ref.

`static void compile(string line, ref string code)`

and call it with a ref, e.g. `compile("function Main {", ref code);`

Comment: Thanks! That worked exactly right. I can now fix a few problems, add some more options, and move on to executing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working as expected because even though string is a reference type, it is actually passed by value.  That means that each time you are passing in string, you are passing in a blank string, and nothing is being done to it.  See this post:

[C# string reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096449/c-sharp-string-reference-type)

You can fix it by declaring it an "out" variable.

```
static void compile(string line, out string code)
```

Or better yet, change compile to return the string.

```
static string compile(string line, string code)
```

and then invoke it like this:

```
code = compile("code bits",code);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Lasse V. Karlsen suggested, you may pass `code` by reference (using `ref`), but the best solution would be to use a `StringBuilder` since it's mutable and this will save you tens of useless `string` instantiations:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
            Compile("function Main {", code);
            Compile("x = Hello world!!", code);
            Compile("print x", code);
            Compile("input x", code);
            Compile("} ;", code);

            Console.WriteLine(code);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    static void Compile(string line, StringBuilder code)
    {
        string[] tokens = line.Split(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
        {
            if (tokens[i].Contains("function"))
            {
                code.Append(":")
                    .Append(tokens[i+1]);
                i++;
            }
            else if (tokens[i].Contains("="))
            {

                code.Append("PUSH ")
                    .Append(tokens[i-1])
                    .Append("\n")
                    .Append("PUSH ")
                    .Append(tokens[i+1])
                    .Append("\n")
                    .Append("SET\n");
                i++;
            }
            else if (tokens[i].Contains("exec"))
            {
                code.Append("GOTO ")
                    .Append(tokens[i+1])
                    .Append("\n");
                i++;
            }
            else if (tokens[i].Contains("}"))
            {
                code.Append("RTN\n");
            }
            else if (tokens[i].Contains("input"))
            {
                code.Append("PUSH ")
                    .Append(tokens[i+1])
                    .Append("\nPUSH NULL\nINPUT\n");
            }
            else if (tokens[i].Contains("print"))
            {
                code.Append("PUSH ")
                    .Append(tokens[i+1])
                    .Append("\nPUSH NULL\nPRINT\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `string` is immutable and that you're not passing the parameter by reference.

You're sending in a string variable to the method, but the method cannot change the contents of the variable, it can only change the parameter it has access to, which functions pretty much like a local variable.

Thus, whatever it is the `compile` method does to the `code` parameter does not change the contents of the `code` variable in the main method.

To fix this, change the parameter to a *pass by reference*  parameter by adding the `ref` keyword:

```
static void compile(string line, ref string code)
```

To call it:

```
compile("function Main {", ref code);
```

Observations:

- You've forgotten a newline after the ":Main" program label in your output
- `PUSH x` and `PUSH Hello` does not distinguish between a variable or a literal (string in this case), you probably want to fix this, typically by adding quotes, ie. `PUSH "Hello"`