# calculator runtime error

Tags: c#, runtime, calculator

This morning I created a windows form project to make a calculator from what I've learned and to self learn myself some programming.

Everything was fine , I could make the number buttons print the specific number in the text box , and the operator buttons clears the text box so you can write the second number , but when I press equal"=" I get this run time error :

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String

And I will show you the code in the form1 class (as usual its the only class I have to edit) :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<string> theNumberList = new List<string>();

    public string numbers = null;

    int number1, number2;
    string num1, num2, operat;

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theNumberList.Add("1");
        ShowNumbers(theNumberList, numbers, textBox1);
    }

    public static void ShowNumbers(List<string> theList, string aString, TextBox textBox)
    {
        foreach(string number in theList)
        {
            aString = aString + number;
            textBox.Text = aString;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theNumberList.Add("2");
        ShowNumbers(theNumberList, numbers, textBox1);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theNumberList.Add("3");
        ShowNumbers(theNumberList, numbers, textBox1);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theNumberList.Add("4");
        ShowNumbers(theNumberList, numbers, textBox1);
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theNumberList.Add("5");
        ShowNumbers(theNumberList, numbers, textBox1);
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theNumberList.Add("6");
        ShowNumbers(theNumberList, numbers, textBox1);
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theNumberList.Add("7");
        ShowNumbers(theNumberList, numbers, textBox1);
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theNumberList.Add("8");
        ShowNumbers(theNumberList, numbers, textBox1);
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theNumberList.Add("9");
        ShowNumbers(theNumberList, numbers, textBox1);
    }

    private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theNumberList.Add("0");
        ShowNumbers(theNumberList, numbers, textBox1);
    }

    private void Plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = numbers;
        theNumberList.Clear();
        num2 = numbers;
        operat = "+";
    }

    private void Subtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Multiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Divide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int result;
        switch (operat)
        {
            case "+":
                number1 = int.Parse(num1);
                number2 = int.Parse(num2);
                result = number1 + number2;
                theNumberList.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

so this is the code and the error comes at Equal_click in "number1 = int.parse(num1);" here :

```
private void Equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int result;
        switch (operat)
        {
            case "+":
                number1 = int.Parse(num1);
                number2 = int.Parse(num2);
                result = number1 + number2;
                theNumberList.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to fix it and what is wrong ?

Comment: Please make your sample smaller - check http://sscce.org/ for guidance. Also avoid "I'm new here", "thank you" and similar text not directly related to your problem.

Comment: The compiler is right the value is null, num1 = numbers but where do you assign a value to numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the exception because `num1` is null.  In this function:

```
public static void ShowNumbers(List<string> theList, string aString, TextBox textBox)
{
    foreach(string number in theList)
    {
        aString = aString + number;
        textBox.Text = aString;
    }
}
```

you are setting the value of aString, but not `numbers`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096449/c-sharp-string-reference-type) for why passing the string this way does not work.  You need to change it to use the `numbers` variable.  Note we also make it a member function instead of static:

```
public void ShowNumbers()
{
    foreach(string number in theNumberList)
    {
        numbers = numbers + number;
        textBox1.Text = numbers;
    }
}
```

Also, there is another issue.  You need to assign `num2` when you press `=` not when you press `+`.

Answer (score 0):

It means your num1 is most likely empty and it cant convert the empty string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse can parse Strings which are in numeric mode like => "9"
so when num1 is null or num1 = "" ; int.parse, can't parse it to int

try this

instead of **Parse** you should use **TryParse**

```
int.TryParse(string,out int)
```