# String is reference types but when we pass it as a parameter in function it works as value types why?

Tags: c#

I have following code snippet. when i pass string strMain into foo method and print it then i get "main" string, if string is reference type then why it prints "main" not "local". when i do same thing by passing it with ref keyword then it works. string is reference types then why it needs ref keyword here.

```
void main()
{
   string strMain="main"
   foo(string str);
   Console.WriteLine(strMain);
}
void foo(string strFoo )
{
   strFoo="Local";
}
```

Comment: The "handle" (the reference) is a value and is passed as such (as a copy). In `foo` you simply change what the *copy* refers to. If you want to work on the same "handle" (reference) you need to declare the parameter `ref`. That would pass the reference by reference ;-).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# string reference type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096449/c-sharp-string-reference-type)

Answer (score 1):

The reason this works the way it does is that you are passing `strFoo` by value, not by reference. Re-assigning `strFoo` inside `foo` to a new `string` has no effect on `strMain` from `main`. This is not specific to `string`: all reference types in C# work in this way.

If you want to make the assignment in `foo` be visible in `main`, pass your string by reference:

```
public void Main(string[] args) {
    string strMain="main";
    Foo(ref strMain);
    Console.WriteLine(strMain);
}
void Foo(ref string strFoo) {
     strFoo="Local";
}
```

Note that passing a reference type by value allows the method being called to change the value of the variable that you pass, as long as that variable is *mutable*. This cannot be done with `string` because it is immutable, but you can do it with a `StringBuilder`:

```
public void Main(string[] args) {
    StringBuilder strMain=new StringBuilder();
    Foo(strMain);
    Console.WriteLine(strMain);
}
void Foo(StringBuilder strFoo) {
     strFoo.Append("Local");
}
```

Here is an illustration:

[image: Pass by value vs. pass by reference.]

Comment: in my given code strMain itself is reference type then why do we need to pass it with ref explicitly??

Comment: @PraveenDeewan Being a reference type has nothing to do with passing parameters by reference (I know, this sounds extremely confusing). When you pass by reference, the reference is to the variable (i.e. to `strMain`) is passed, and `strMain` is also a reference to the string `"main"`; essentially, you pass a double reference. When you pass by value, it's a single reference that's being passed - i.e. the reference to string `"main"`.

Comment: can you just explain me object creation scenario of this by drawing or any source link because i am not satisfied with this ref concept of reference variable. How it gets resolved.

Comment: ahh... got the concept how it works with ref now totally satisfied, thanks a lot @dasblinkenlight