# converting "&" in C to C#

Tags: c#, c, pointers, ampersand

Some C code

```
#include aes.h

void encryption(unsigned char aes_key[16], unsigned char _buff[16], unsigned char _iv[16]){

unsigned long encrypt = 1;
unsigned char output[];

AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, 128, &key);
for(i = 0; i > 16 ; i ++){
       AES_cbc_encrypt(&_buff[i], output, 16, &key, _iv, encrypt);
       }
 }
```

How to do '&_buff[i]' in C#? I've been trying to use

```
_buff[i]
```

in C# but it gives different result.
Does anyone know how to do this? It would be big help.

Comment: We need more context. What are you specifically trying to do?

Comment: Thats the address-of operator in C, and without context about what you are trying to do, its hard to say if you need it. 99% of the time you don't need pointers and address-of in c#

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for these search terms: [C# string pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096449/c-sharp-string-reference-type)

That C code is actually wrong and a bad example. In general, you can pass a string in order to change it. See the example below with `change(buf)`. Also `change(&buf[0])` will work, but it's weird. Or you can say change(buf+3), this will change the string beginning at 3rd character.

```
void change(char *buf){
    strcpy(buf, "changed");
}

int main(){
    char buf[50];
    strcpy(buf, "0123456789");
    change(buf);// result => buf = "chagned"
    //change(&buf[0]);//result => buf = "chagned"
    //change(buf + 3);//result => buf = "012changed"
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

And then there is `buf[0]` which is a single character. It's different than `&buf[0]`

Comment: so, that's what "&" is for. Thank you for the explanation.