# How to change a null string to default

Tags: c#, string, null

For a project I need  to change a string affected to null or a white space to default.
   In my head this code makes sense but what am I missing? It just return a whitespace like it hasnt changed at all. I'm new to programming and I'm looking for help. Thank you :).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "";
        ValidateString(s);
        Console.WriteLine(s);

    }
    static string ValidateString(string s)
    {
        if (s == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            s = "défault";
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Note: I found out I could just add a "ref". Isn't there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# string reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096449/c-sharp-string-reference-type)

Comment: @FrankerZ surprisingly that (good) duplicate does not show how to actually deal with strings (so not hammering)... Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working would do better?

Comment: FYI, `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` returns `true` if the string is `null`, so you don't need `s == null` in addition to that.

Answer (score 6):

You're returning the value from the method, but you're not capturing that return value.  Update the variable with the returned value:

```
string s = "";
s = ValidateString(s); // <--- here
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Or, more simply:

```
Console.WriteLine(ValidateString(""));
```

---

Your method itself could also be simplified to:

```
return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? "défault" : s;
```

Answer (score -1):

`s` not change because you ignore the return value of the `ValidateString` method, change your code like below:

```
s= ValidateString(s);
```

and the `ValidateString` can imporved like this:

```
static string ValidateString(string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? "défault" : s;
}
```

Comment: A good optimization of the method, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Would be helpful if you added an explanation of what the OP was doing incorrectly, and how this solves the problem (code-only answers are often not as helpful without some description)