# C#: Using one Data Table in order to fill 2 different comboboxes?

Tags: c#, combobox, datatable, fill

I have 2 comboboxes on a form (form1) called combobox1 and combobox2.

Each comboboxes should be filled with data stored in 2 different tables in Sql server 2005: table1 and table2

I mean: combobox1 --> table1        combobox2 --> table2

I fill data table with proper data and then bind the comboboxes to it separately.

My problem is: after filling 2 combos, both of them have equal data got from table2.

This is my code:

```
        DataTable tb1 = new DataTable();

        //Filling tb1 with data got from table1
        combobox1.Items.Clear();
        combobox1.DataSource = tb1;
        combobox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        combobox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

        //filling tb1 with data got from table2
        combobox2.Items.Clear();
        combobox2.DataSource = tb1;
        combobox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
        combobox2.ValueMember = "ID";
        combobox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

What's wrong?

It seems that if I get 2 different data tables (tb1 and tb2) , every thing will be all right.

Any suggestions please.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`DataTable` is a reference type, which means that when you assign tb1 to the DataSource of a control, you are actually assigning a reference/link in memory to the `DataSource`. Therefor when you modify the tb1 variable you are changing the reference itself. Because you are only changing the reference, the `DataSource` still looks at the same `DataTable`, only now it has a different set of Data.

Comment: ok, so you think I should have 2 different data tables for filling 2 combos?

Comment: If you have similar Data, then Mitch's answer would be better. If you are pulling back two entirely different DataTables, then just declare two DataTables.

Comment: Thank you, but why what you said above is NOT correct when we use string. I mean as we know, string is a reference type. 
string s = "hello";
textbox1.Text = s;
s = "world";
textbox2.Text = s;

In code snippet above, textbox1.Text has value  "hello"  and textbox2.Text has "world".  right?

Comment: Yes it is correct. String is pretty much an exception to the rule. check out this SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type. And here's an article on Value vs Reference types that might help you understand this fundamental part of the language: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 separate `DataView`'s on the DataTable(), and bind each combobox to a DataView,.

See [DataView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx)