# In .NET, what is the rationale for Strings initializing to null?

Tags: .net, string, initialization

I understand that String is an object, as opposed to say Int, and object variables generally don't point to anything unless you create the object. So I know how it works.

But, in terms of simple, practical programming, why doesn't .NET initialise a string as empty (""), as that is surely the most common use of the string variable - as a string, not as an object?

I've never (yet) had need for a string to be null, that is "not a string". It seems to be a rare requirement. I'm unable to say an int variable is null, so why do so with string? Having it as an option is undoubtedly necessary, but why does .NET make it null to begin with, when int etc. are given proper initial values?

I'm asking because I like to understand not just how something works but why, as it reduced my desire to rant about how weird it seems. :)

Comment: You haven't had a need for distinguishing between "no string" and "empty string"? That's really strange; what kind of code do you write? For example, there is no string before reading something in from the user; but there is an empty string afterward, if the user chose to enter nothing.

Answer (score 7):

Strings are not initialized as `null`. You are confusing initialization with declaration. Whenever you declare a variable like:

```
 Foo myFoo;
```

It starts out as null until you actually call its constructor. Like so:

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
```

Now traditionally you don't call constructors for the string class, you instantiate them with string literals like this:

```
string myString = "foo";
```

There are constructors for the string class though, a few of them, but they all take some array of characters / bytes to use to create the string. What never happens is this:

```
// initialize an empty string ("")
string myString = new string();
```

This is because the string class is **immutable**, that is once it has been instantiated you can never change it, you can only create a new string and set your variable to point to it (this is why all the methods of the string class return a new string rather than changing the one you called the method on). So really it makes no sense to initialize to some default value because once you had done so you would be stuck with it.

Comment: If string is member of a class it is initialized to null even if you don't explicitly give it a literal value

Comment: +1, although if you declare an object in a method body, it is uninitialized, not null.

Comment: @Hasan No, again here you are using the word initialized incorrectly. **NULL** is a general concept in computer science. It is used to signify that a pointer is uninitialized and does not point to anything. When you create an instance of a class any member fields that are not initialized (have their values set or constructor called) will be `null` identifying them as uninitialized. Here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#Null_pointer

Answer (score 4):

`String` is a reference type. The default value for *all* reference types is `null`. This is defined by the C# language and there is no way to change this behaviour.

Even if the designers of the `String` class *wanted* the value of `default(String)` to be the empty string (which I doubt) it's simply not possible to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `string` is a reference type and reference types default to `null`. It's just consistent behavior. I would be surprised if it defaulted to something else.

I can think of an example where null strings as the default value actually makes sense. Let's say you are parsing the following XML nodes for the name `attribute`.

```
<node name=""/>
<node />
```

Given the following struct, how can one differentiate the 2 nodes?

```
struct Node
{
  public string Name { get; }
}
```

For `<node name=""/>`, your parser sees the `name` attribute and then sets `Node.Name` to `string.Empty`. For `<node />`, your parser doesn't see the `name` attribute and doesn't assign anything.

Thus you're left with `Node.Name==string.Empty` for the first node and the second node would have `Node.Name==null`. Which makes sense.

Comment: Don't give this consistence explanation. `Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (== and !=) are defined to compare the values of string objects, not references. ` Decisions are not always made to be consistent.

Comment: Ok, -1 for the example. The question is not about string being null. But why the initialization is null. And read this line from OP - `Having it as an option is undoubtedly necessary, but why does .NET make it null to begin with, when int etc. are given proper initial values?`

Comment: @manojlds: About the example code, the null default makes sense because you don't have to assign something to Name if you can't see the name attribute. I've edited my answer to hopefully make this clearer.

Comment: I still don't agree with the example in this context, but have removed my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

The question is connected to another question [Why is string a reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655984/why-is-string-a-reference-type)

When they choosed `string`s to be reference types, clearly they had to make `default(string) == null`, in the same way that `default(any reference type) == null`.

A more intelligent question is then "why are strings reference types instead of, for example, a `struct String { private char[] MyInternalSting; }`? Because they decided so (even the link that I have given gives more cyrcular thinking logic than real reasons... Like "because otherwhise you couldn't do `Object.ReferenceEquals`" as if you could do `Object.ReferenceEquals` with numbers and other value types).

Some other intelligent questions could be why `"A" + null == "A"` instead of `NullPointerException` or `ArgumentNullException`? (i wasn't able to find an intelligent response... Perhaps for compatibility with VB.NET)