# why String is designed Class/Object in Java, which uses more resources

Tags: java, string

Well, String is an often used type, working as an Object consumes more resource,
why Sun designed it as an Object but not a simple variable like int

if someone says String can contain very long sentence, why it was not designed to be like int and Integer

Comment: All primitives have **fixed** length.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655984/why-is-string-a-reference-type)

Comment: `To retain primitive types in an object-oriented language` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17489410/1927832

Answer (score 4):

There are some advantage of being an Object instead of primitives

1. No size limit
2. you can implement utility methods for helping operations
3. you can make it immutable

Comment: Arnt Java Strings immutable by definition as you cannot change them?

Comment: it's not immutable by itself. it was made immutable .. and it was possible as it was a class

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more efficient with storing text in memory you can keep it in a byte array.