# If string is reference type, why pass by reference is not happening?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, pass-by-reference, value-type

I had read an article http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

As per this, `int` is a value type and `form` is an example of reference type.

```
Point myPoint = new Point (0, 0);      // a new value-type variable
Form myForm = new Form();              // a new reference-type variable
string mystringval="test";
Test (myPoint, myForm);                // Test is a method defined below

void Test (Point p, Form f)
{
      p.X = 100;                       // No effect on MyPoint since p is a copy
      f.Text = "Hello, World!";        // This will change myForm’s caption since
                                       // myForm and f point to the same object
      f = null;                        // No effect on myForm
}
```

So instead of form variable `myform`, if I pass a string value to the function test, will it also change the original value which I already declared outside?

Also what is the benefit of keeping the string as reference type, if, anyhow the value will be saved in stack and only the reference will be stored in heap?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type

Comment: @GrantWinney, if strings are immutable, why its not updated with the last value provided? why should i give ref to a reference type?

Answer (score 4):

> if i pass a string value to the function test, will it also change the original value which i already declared outside?

No, neither did the value of `myForm` change, the `myForm` variable still points/refers to the same `Form` object (the object created via `new Form()`).

In your `Test` method, when you called:

```
f.Text = "Hello, World!";
```

You did not change the variable `f`, you changed `f.Text` which is a different.

In other words, you are changing a property on the object that both `f` and `myForm` refer to. But still `f` and `myForm` refer to the same original object.

Note that when you changed `f` to `null`, the variable `myForm` did not change. Now, `f` refers to nothing, but the `myForm` variable still refers to the original object.

If you want to change the original `myForm` variable (make it point/refer to another `Form` object) or `mystringval` (make it refer to another string) then pass them to the test method by reference like this:

```
void Test (Point p, ref Form f)
{
    ...
}

void Test (Point p, ref string s)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you ..i understood your point. So the string is categorized as reference type as it may contain huge data which cannot handled by stack. am i right?

Comment: If it so, the value of string will be stored in heap? what is the benefit of keeping the string in heap?

Comment: I believe it's not a matter of choice. Because of the nature of strings size, it needs to be in the heap. After all in c, string is just a pointer to memory where the end is marked by a /0. Could be wrong here since I'm rather new to c#.

Comment: @user833985 - I think you've got a few misconceptions about the stack and the heap.You should ignore the distinction as it doesn't really matter to the behavour of the objects as to where they are stored. What you should focus on are these two concepts - "value vs reference types" & "mutable vs immutable types".

Comment: Correct. The heap vs. the stack are implementation details. The CLR certainly doesn't use the size of objects as a determining factor in where the object is stored. And even if it did, it'd be required to make sure that the behavior of objects didn't change if they crossed a size threshold and ended up being stored in a different data structure. That would lead to severely non-deterministic programs.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655984/why-is-string-a-reference-type) explains why string is categorized as a reference type.