# How to restrict T to value types using a constraint?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, constraints

I want to restrict the possible types N can take-on using a constraint.  I wish to restrict N to be either a int or a decimal.

```
public static Chart PopulateInto<T, N>(List<T> yAxis, List<N> xAxis) where N : int, decimal
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: If those are the only two types you care about I think you could just overload the method. Sure it's 4 overloads but that's not too bad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to specify generic type constraints that only allow specific value types. More to the point, it wouldn't make much sense even if it was allowed.

You're allowed to specify a class as a generic constraint but this is because you can inherit from classes, the constraint thus sets the minimum threshold of what types you're allowed to use.

If this was allowed for value types, where you cannot inherit from those types, you would effectively limit yourself to only that type.

Thus you cannot do this, but you have a few alternatives:

- You can declare it without the constraint, and handle the problem at runtime. *I would not recommend this way*
- You can declare overloads that take the specific types you're interested in.

  Since you only have two such types this is what I would recommend doing.

Here are the overloads you would declare:

```
public static Chart PopulateInto<T>(List<T> yAxis, List<int> xAxis)
{
    // Do stuff here
}

public static Chart PopulateInto<T>(List<T> yAxis, List<decimal> xAxis)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

---

Now, additionally, if your *handling* of those values doesn't really rely on the numeric quality of those types, you just want to limit which types you can handle, then you can always declare your original method as well, *privately*, and call this method from your overloads. This would still limit your code to only allowing `int` or `decimal`, *publicly*, but your implementation would still be generic. Without knowing exactly what "Do stuff here" entails it is impossible to tell if this is a viable option or not but here is the code anyway:

```
public static Chart PopulateInto<T>(List<T> yAxis, List<int> xAxis)
{
    return PopulateInto<T, int>(yAxis, xAxis);
}

public static Chart PopulateInto<T>(List<T> yAxis, List<decimal> xAxis)
{
    return PopulateInto<T, decimal>(yAxis, xAxis);
}

private static Chart PopulateInto<T, N>(List<T> yAxis, List<N> xAxis) where N : struct
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: And my generics are off, that's what I get for writing answers on Friday night, let me correct that.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive criticism. Unfortunately the question **in the title** is misleading, because if we limit ourselves to that then the answer is easy: `where N : struct`. However, the real question only has one real, definitive, answer, and that is "That is not possible with the current allowed C# syntax". I have expanded my answer to cover all the options though, hope it wastes less of peoples time going forward.

Answer (score 24):

**It's not possible to constrain a generic parameter to a specific value type.**

You can however force it to be *a* value type or `struct` by adding `where N : struct`, but that's all.

Comment: An alternative way to handle it is to have specific overloads for `int` or `decimal` lists.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to do this with a constraint.  Another approach though, assuming that `PopulateInto` can work with a generic N, is to make the core algorihtm generic and private and offer 2 public overloads which take an `int` and `decimal` respectively.  This will create a similar effect

```
public static Chart PopulateInto<T>(
  List<T> yAxis, 
  List<decimal> xAxis) {

  return PopulateIntoCore(yAxis, xAxis);
}

public static Chart PopulateInto<T>(
  List<T> yAxis, 
  List<int> xAxis) {

  return PopulateIntoCore(yAxis, xAxis);
}

private static Chart PopulateIntoCore<T, N>(
  List<T> yAxis, 
  List<N> xAxis) where N : struct {
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Mark, yeah, that would be the crux of my answer ;) Fixed

Answer (score 4):

As Pieter said, you cannot use a compile-time check to to this. However, you can do the following at runtime:

```
if(!(typeof(N).equals(typeof(int32))) && !(typeof(N).equals(typeof(decimal))))
  // do something
```

Comment: Yeah, why not.  Throw an InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in the ***Title*** but not the body of the question.

To cover **all** types commonly meant by `Value Types` (which includes [Nullable Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types), and also `string` even though it's [technically a Reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type)), you need 3 overloads:

```
public void Foo<T>(T arg) where T : struct
public void Foo<T?>(T? arg) where T : struct
public void Foo<string>(string arg)
```

From the [MSDN Docs on generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

> `where T : struct`       The type argument must be a non-nullable value type.

Answer (score 2):

The closet you can get is Where T: struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible.
All value types implements these interfaces.