# Using generics possible to limit supplied types to Built-In?

Tags: c#

I would like to limit the data types my method accepts using generics to built in types:

Built in types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds(v=vs.80).aspx

The list differs from value / reference types. And I would like to only support built in, not all value types, and ofc also string, which is a reference type.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

Using constraints you can restrict to value types like this:

```
T GetObject<T> where T: struct;
```

This would not permit strings to pass through though.

Comment: Doesn't look like it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Just write an overload for each type?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Generic constraints to include value types AND strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745444/c-sharp-generic-constraints-to-include-value-types-and-strings)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I'm not looking for value+string, but built in types.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do with generics.

If you need to do this and retain compile-time checking your only option is to provide overloads of your method with different parameter types so that all the built-in types are covered.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately it isn't possible.

The closest I think you could do is below:

```
T GetObject<T>()
{
    if (!(typeof(T) is typeof(int)
        || typeof(T) is typeof(uint)
        ...
        || typeof(T) is typeof(string)))
    {
        //Custom exception class for this purpose
        throw new TypeArgumentException("Invalid type parameter \"T\".");
    }

    ...
}
```

Not quite as nice, but does the job.