# How to implicitly convert nullable type to non-nullable type

Tags: c#, .net

I have a nullable c# 10 .net 6 project with an extension method to `ThrowIfNull`

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

#nullable enable
public static class NullExtensions
{
    public static T ThrowIfNull<T>(
        this T? argument, 
        string? message = default, 
        [CallerArgumentExpression("argument")] string? paramName = default
    )
    {
        if (argument is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName, message);
        }
        else
        {
            return argument;
        }
    }
}
```

The extension method implicitly converts `string?` to `string` but it does not work for other primitive types like `int?` or `bool?`

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        
        string? foo = "foo";
        string nonNullableFoo = foo.ThrowIfNull();  // success from "string?" to "string"
        Console.WriteLine(nonNullableFoo);
        
        bool? baz = true;
        bool nonNullableBaz = baz.ThrowIfNull();    // success from "string?" to "string"
        Console.WriteLine(nonNullableFoo);
        
        int? bar = 2;
        int nonNullableBar = bar.ThrowIfNull(); // error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'
        Console.WriteLine(nonNullableBar);
    }
}
```

How do I make the extension implicitly convert `int?` and `bool?`?

Here is the full dotnet fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/LiQ8NL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by providing one extension method for non-nullable reference types and another for unmanaged (e.g. int, bool, ...) types. Note that unmanaged types require a cast.

```
public static class NullExtensions
{
    public static T ThrowIfNull<T>(
        this T? argument,
        string? message = default,
        [CallerArgumentExpression("argument")] string? paramName = default
    ) where T : notnull
    {
        if (argument is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName, message);
        }
        else
        {
            return argument;
        }
    }

    public static T ThrowIfNull<T>(
        this T? argument,
        string? message = default,
        [CallerArgumentExpression("argument")] string? paramName = default
    ) where T : unmanaged
    {
        if (argument is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName, message);
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)argument;
        }
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
int? foo = 42;
int bar = foo.ThrowIfNull();
Console.WriteLine(bar);

string? baz = "Hello";
string quus = baz.ThrowIfNull();
Console.WriteLine(quus);

// Comment out either this
baz = null;
quus = baz.ThrowIfNull();
// Or this
foo = null;
bar = foo.ThrowIfNull();
```

Comment: TIL: `notnull` and `managed`. Accepting this as the answer. Thanks! Full fiddle for future reference is here https://dotnetfiddle.net/fjwIo7

Answer (score 5):

###### Using the null-coalescing Operator `??`

To assign a nullable value to a non-null variable, consider the following code:

```cs
int? value = 28;
int result = value ?? -1;
Console.WriteLine($"The result is {result}");
```

- Output: `The result is 28`

```cs
int? value = null;
int result = value ?? -1;
Console.WriteLine($"The result is {result}");
```

- Output: `The result is -1`

---

###### Editing The Code

Rearrange the code as follows. Therefore `bool?` You can use the type implicitly:

```cs
int? bar = 2;
int nonNullableBar = bar ?? -1; 
Console.WriteLine(nonNullableBar);
```

```cs
bool? baz = true;
bool nonNullableBaz = false;
        
if (baz == true){ 
    nonNullableBaz = true;
} 
else if(baz == false){ 
    nonNullableBaz = false;
} 
else {
    /* Something */
}
```

---

###### References

- [Nullable Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)
- [Boolean Logical Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)

Comment: This is explicitly casting a nullable value (int?) to the same nullable value (int?) which is not what I wanted. I want to implicitly cast a nulalble value (int?) into non-nullable value (int)

Comment: This is the first time I've come across this usage. This is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Assigning a magic value like -1 to represent null isn't a good practice.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: What if -1 is valid input? The issue is particularly apparent when you consider `bool?`

Comment: `bool` in basic data type `??` operator is unavailable. In an `int` data type, if the variable takes the value -1, doesn't that mean it's not `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Found one possible option in MS dotnet docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

> Constraint "where T : struct"     The type argument must be a non-nullable value type

Also according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8745492/2877168 it is not possible to make this work for `string?` and all other value types. So only way is to define two extension methods. Here is the updated version that works for `string?` and `int?`, `bool?` etc

```cs
public static class NullExtensions
{
    public static T ThrowIfNull<T>(this T? argument, string? message = default, [CallerArgumentExpression("argument")] string? paramName = default)
        where T : struct
    {
        if (argument is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName, message);
        return (T)argument;
    }

    public static string ThrowIfNull(this string? argument, string? message = default, [CallerArgumentExpression("argument")] string? paramName = default)
    {
        if (argument is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName, message);
        return argument;
    }
}
```

A working version of this is at https://dotnetfiddle.net/uBX1w6