How to add numbers of a generic type
I have a collection of objects that have a unique key. That key could be numbers or a string, it's generic and most of the class doesn't care because it's stored in a Dictionary<TKey, TItem>.
Now the class should provide a method to return a new unique key for an item to be added. That's where I can't find a solution. I've tried to read up on the new generic math feature of C# but that doesn't make any sense to me.
I'm looking for something like the GetUniqueKey method below:
// Restrict TKey to numbers or strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30660880
class MyCollection<TKey, TObject>
    where TObject : class
    where TKey : notnull, IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<TKey>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TObject> items;

    public TKey GetUniqueKey()
    {
        if (TKey is INumber)
            return items.Keys.Max() + 1;
        if (TKey is string)
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        throw new NotSupportedException("Key type not supported.");
    }
}

Can this be done at all?

Not yet, but it's in progress...

MAX+1 isn't a great way of generating unique keys. It guarantees duplicates if items are deleted. A far better way would be to store the last generated ID and increment it each time.

Hm, I cannot see how this guarantees duplicates if it only generates a value that never exists at the time. I am aware that this is not to be compared with SQL sequences. It's a local data store only.

This is what I came up with:
// Restrict TKey to numbers or strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30660880
public class MyCollection<TObject, TKey>
    where TObject : class
    where TKey : notnull, IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<TKey>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TObject> objects = [];

    public TKey GetUniqueKey()
    {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(TKey)))
        {
            case TypeCode.SByte:
            case TypeCode.Byte:
            case TypeCode.Int16:
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
            case TypeCode.Int32:
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
            case TypeCode.Int64:
                if (Count == 0)
                    return (TKey)Convert.ChangeType(1, typeof(TKey));
                return (TKey)Convert.ChangeType(Convert.ToInt64(objects.Keys.Max()) + 1, typeof(TKey));
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                if (Count == 0)
                    return (TKey)Convert.ChangeType(1, typeof(TKey));
                return (TKey)Convert.ChangeType(Convert.ToUInt64(objects.Keys.Max()) + 1, typeof(TKey));
            case TypeCode.String:
                return (TKey)(object)Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Key type {typeof(TKey).Name} not supported.");
        }
    }
}

I makes use of IConvertible for all numbers to convert the types, any also IComparable for Max().

Are you interested in a dictionary that can mix both numbers and strings in the same instance? Or is a particular instance always of a fixed key type?

TKey is fixed in an instance. But I can have int-keyed and string-keyed entities in separate collections. This is a distant replacement for EF's DbSet.

It seems to me that the trick is to use a Create factory, which passes in an appropriate GetUniqueKey method as a delegate
public MyCollection<TKey, TObject> CreateNumberCollection<TKey, TObject>()
        where TKey : INumberBase<TKey> =>
    new MyCollection<TKey, TObject>(lastKey => lastKey++);

public MyCollection<string, TObject> CreateStringCollection<TObject>() =>
    new MyCollection<string, TObject>(lastKey => Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

public MyCollection<Guid, TObject> CreateGuidCollection<TObject>() =>
    new MyCollection<Guid, TObject>(lastKey => Guid.NewGuid());


public class MyCollection<TKey, TObject>
    where TObject : class
    where TKey : notnull, IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<TKey>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TObject> _items = new();

    private TKey _lastKey;

    private Func<TKey, TKey> _uniqueKeyFactory;

    public MyCollection(Func<TKey, TKey> uniqueKeyFactory)
    {
        _uniqueKeyFactory = uniqueKeyFactory;
    }

    public TKey GetUniqueKey() =>
        _lastKey = _uniqueKeyFactory(_lastKey);
}

If you want to do this entirely from a single function then you could store those delegates in a dictionary.
private static Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _factories = new(){
    { typeof(int), new Func<int, int>(lastKey => lastKey++) },
    { typeof(byte), new Func<int, byte>(lastKey => lastKey++) },
    { typeof(double), new Func<int, double>(lastKey => lastKey++) },
    { typeof(Guid), new Func<int, Guid>(lastKey => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) },
    { typeof(string), new Func<int, string>(lastKey => Guid.NewGuid()) },
};

And then
    public MyCollection()
    {
        if (!_factories.TryGetValue(typeof(TKey), out var uniqueKeyFactory))
            throw new Exception("Invaid type");

        _uniqueKeyFactory = (Func<TKey, TKey>)uniqueKeyFactory;
    }


Looks like offloading the problem to the caller of the class. Also, these generated keys are not unique after adding some items with existing keys.

Well someone somewhere needs to decide what function to call. You could perhaps store the delegates in a static dictionary and pull them out dynamically. As for existing keys: you are always going to have that problem, there's no indication in the question that you'd even considered that or what you'd want to do about it.

You can indeed use the generic math APIs here, but you will still need some way to convince the compiler that TKey is a number. For the string case, you can simply check typeof(TKey) == typeof(string) and do some casts.
Here is an example doing this by dynamically binding to a helper method:
private Dictionary<TKey, TObject> items = ...;
public TKey GetUniqueKey()
{
    if (typeof(TKey).GetInterface("System.Numerics.INumber`1") != null)
        return GetNumericUniqueKey((dynamic)items.Keys);
    if (typeof(TKey) == typeof(string))
        return (TKey)(object)Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    throw new NotSupportedException("Key type not supported.");
}

private static T GetNumericUniqueKey<T>(ICollection<T> existingKeys) where T: INumber<T> {
    if (existingKeys.Any()) {
        return (existingKeys.Max() ?? T.Zero) + T.One;
    }
    return T.Zero;
}


Another approach is to abstract away the idea that keys must be strings or numbers. Create an IKey interface that requires its implementations to have the behaviours you need:
interface IKey<TSelf> where TSelf: IKey<TSelf> {
    static abstract TSelf GetUniqueKey(ICollection<TSelf> existingKeys);
    
    // declare other useful things you might want a key to have here
}

Then MyCollection can be as simple as:
class MyCollection<TKey, TObject>
    where TObject : class
    where TKey : IKey<TKey>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TObject> items = ...;

    public TKey GetUniqueKey()
    {
        return TKey.GetUniqueKey(items.Keys);
    }
}

Now you just need to implement numeric keys and string keys as simple wrappers of numeric types and string. Again, you can use generic math to implement numeric keys.
record struct NumericKey<T>(T number): IKey<NumericKey<T>> where T: INumber<T> {
    
    public static NumericKey<T> GetUniqueKey(ICollection<NumericKey<T>> existingKeys) {
        if (existingKeys.Any()) {
            var newKey = (existingKeys.Max(x => x.number) ?? T.Zero) + T.One;
            return new NumericKey<T>(newKey);
        }
        return new NumericKey<T>(T.Zero);
    }
    
    // add implicit conversions perhaps...
}

record struct StringKey(string str): IKey<StringKey> {
    public static StringKey GetUniqueKey(ICollection<StringKey> existingKeys) {
        return new StringKey(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
    
    // add implicit conversions perhaps...
}

If you don't mind MyCollection having 3 type parameters, you can do this without changing TKey to wrapper types.
class MyCollection<TKey, TFactory, TObject>
    where TObject : class
    where TKey : notnull, IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<TKey>
    where TFactory: IKeyFactory<TKey>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TObject> items = new();

    public TKey GetUniqueKey()
    {
        return TFactory.GetUniqueKey(items.Keys);
    }
}

interface IKeyFactory<TKey> {
    static abstract TKey GetUniqueKey(ICollection<TKey> existingKeys);
}

sealed class NaximumPlusOneFactory<T>: IKeyFactory<T> where T: INumber<T> {
    private NaximumPlusOneFactory() {}
    public static T GetUniqueKey(ICollection<T> existingKeys) {
        if (existingKeys.Any()) {
            var newKey = (existingKeys.Max() ?? T.Zero) + T.One;
            return newKey;
        }
        return T.Zero;
    }
}
sealed class GuidFactory: IKeyFactory<string> {
    private GuidFactory() {}
    public static string GetUniqueKey(ICollection<string> existingKeys) {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}


Hm. The first solution looks promising, but I can't use dynamic in an AOT project. The second solution requires me to use these custom types instead of int or string which I cannot do. The key is one of the properties of the objects in my collection, and these simple types are used everywhere.

@ygoe I don't see why you cannot use custom types. What does "the key is one of the properties of the objects in my collection" has anything to do with this? Adding an implicit conversion operator wouldn't help either? Well bottom line is you check every numeric type by hand. e.g. if (typeof(TKey) == typeof(int)) plus a lot of casting. You can cast always to/from TKey - cast to object first if you can't do it directly. Of course, unlike the solutions in my answer, this involves boxing.

You want MyCollection<TKey, TObject>, but you might need MyCollection<TKey, TFactory, TObject> where TFactory : ISomething<TKey>. Then you don't need TKey to implement anything so it can be int or string.

@JeremyLakeman Yeah, using 3 generic parameters was my first thought actually, but that requires users to write all 3 type parameters all the time, and I thought that is not very convenient. Then I thought abstracting away the concrete key, plus implicit conversion operators would be a good compromise.

Or just add an ISomething<TKey> constructor argument to pass in the factory explicitly. I think these answers / comments have summarised your available options.

@JeremyLakeman Are you replying to ygoe? You should probably mention them with "@".
