# why string behaves as value type even though it is a reference type in c#

Tags: c#, string, value-type, reference-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, why is String a reference type that behaves like a value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type)

I know string is a reference type since string can be very large and stack is only 1 mb . But programatically while coding i see it behaves like value type 
for eg

```
string func_name(string streg)

{    
streg="hello";

return streg; 

}

-------------

string str="hi";

str= func_name(str);
```

now str gets the value hello ?

why so ? it bahaves exactly like value type here.

Comment: How is this acting like a value type? A reference type would have the same behaviour in this test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it was decided that the `string` type would be **immutable**, but strings can still be very large.

You can read why here:

[Why .NET String is immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable)

And another question similar to yours:

[In C#, why is String a reference type that behaves like a value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type)

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's an immutable type - i.e. you can't change the contents of the object once it's been defined. Jon Skeet gives a pretty good explanation of this concept in relation to the string type [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is because strings are immutable

Consider the example

`string a ="Hello";`
`a=a+"World";`

Eventhough the second line seems like we are modifying the contents of it ,it is not

The CLR will create a new string object with the value `Hello world` and copies the reference of this new object back to the variable a.
The type is immutable but the variable is not.You can always assign a new reference to the variable of type string