# String behaving like a Value Type

Tags: c#, function, value-type, reference-type

I have just written a function and I don't understand why I'm getting the result I am:

```
private void ReplaceIfEmpty(string originalValue, string newValue)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(originalValue))
  {
    originalValue= newValue;
  }
}
```

When I call this function the originalValue is not updated.  My understanding is that a string is a class, therefore it's a reference type, therefore the value I pass in should be updated.  Can you explain why it isn't?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This has nothing to do with reference types vs value types really.

You're changing the value of a parameter:

```
originalValue= newValue;
```

For "normal" parameters which don't have the `ref` or `out` modifier, that change will *never* be visible.

See my [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more information, along with my article on [reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) to make sure you understand why sometimes it "looks" like reference types are passed by reference by default. (They're not: all arguments are passed by value by default, it's just that for reference types, the argument value is a reference, not an object, so changes made to the *object* are still visible from the caller.)

So you *could* make `originalValue` a `ref` parameter - but it would be better to make the method return a `string` instead. I'm generally reluctant to use `ref` parameters; code is *usually* easier to understand without them.

Answer (score 7):

You passed a *reference to a string*. You did not pass a reference to a *variable*. If you want to change a *variable* then you do it like this:

```
private void ReplaceIfEmpty(ref string originalValue, string newValue)  ...
```

The difference is frequently confusing to people.  Think about it this way. Instead of imagining a string, imagine two houses. Now imagine two pieces of paper that have the addresses of those houses; those are *references* to the houses.  And now imagine four drawers that each contain a piece of paper. The drawers are labelled p, q, x and y:

```
void M(House x, House y)
{
    x = y;
}
...
House p = new House("123 Sesame Street");
House q = new House("1600 Pennsylvania Avenue");
M(p, q);
```

What does this program do?  You put a piece of paper that says "123 Sesame Street" in drawer p. You put a piece of paper that says "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue" in drawer q.

You make a photocopy of the paper in drawer p and put the copy in drawer x.  You make a photocopy of the paper in drawer q and put the copy in drawer y.  And then you call M.  M makes a photocopy of what's in drawer y and puts it in drawer x.  **Drawer p is not affected**.

Now consider this case:

```
void M(ref House r, House s)
{
    r = s;
}
...
House p = new House("123 Sesame Street");
House q = new House("1600 Pennsylvania Avenue");
M(ref p, q);
```

What does this program do?  You put a piece of paper that says "123 Sesame Street" in drawer p. You put a piece of paper that says "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue" in drawer q.

**You put a sticky note on drawer p that says "this drawer is also called r".**

You make a photocopy of the paper in drawer q and put the copy in drawer s.

And then you call M.  M makes a photocopy of what's in drawer s and puts it in drawer r, **which is the same as drawer p**.

Make sense?

Comment: Nice analogy. I will try to remember that one when I next have to explain the concept to one of my Juniors.

Answer (score 5):

You are not changing the value of variable that you passed as the parameter `originalValue`, you are trying to assign a new instance to it, which for references means that the variable points to a new reference -  to update a *reference* you need to pass the string by ref - by default references are passed by value so the variable that you pass never gets updated:

```
private void ReplaceIfEmpty(ref string originalValue, string newValue)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(originalValue))
  {
     originalValue = newValue;
  }
}
```

A much better approach would be to just return the new string instead:

```
private string ReplaceIfEmpty(string originalValue, string newValue)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(originalValue))
      return newValue;
   else
      return originalValue;
}
```

Or even more convenient make it an extension method:

```
public static string ReplaceIfEmpty(this string originalValue, 
                                    string replaceValue)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(originalValue))
      return replaceValue;
   else
      return originalValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following assignemnt:

```
originalValue = newValue;
```

You're not changing the string value that was referenced by `originalValue`, you're changing the value of `originalValue` to point to the same location as `newValue`.

Strings are immutable and can't be modified after they're set, only re-assigned.

Comment: That *is* changing the value of `originalValue` - the variable's value is a reference, and this changes it to be a different reference. However, that change isn't visible to callers, because the argument is passed by value.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Poor choice of words on my part. I was referring to the string value that the reference stored. Tried re-wording things to make that more clear. Will probably just delete since I've been blown out of the water.

Comment: Unfortunately wording this sort of thing accurately and readably gets extremely tricky :( I tend to use the word "object" when I'm talking about the object (which is what I think you mean by "the string value").