# Make a reference to another string in C#

Tags: c#, string, value-type, reference-type

As far as I know a string in C# is a reference type.

So in the following code 'a' should be equal to "Hi", but it still keeps its value which is "Hello". Why?

```
string a = "Hello";
string b = a;
b = "Hi";
```

Comment: Check this for details :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable

Comment: @ZeNo: this has nothing to do with string immutability. It's normal reference type behaviour.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A number of the answers point out that strings are immutable; though that is true, it is completely irrelevant to your question.

What is more relevant is that you are misunderstanding how references work with respect to variables. A reference is not a reference to a *variable*. Think of a reference as a piece of string. You start with this:

```
a----------------------Hello
```

Then you say that "b = a", which means *attach another piece of string to the same thing that `a` is attached to*:

```
a----------------------Hello
                      /
b---------------------
```

Then you say "now attach b to Hi"

```
a----------------------Hello

b----------------------Hi
```

You are thinking either that references work like this:

```
a----------------------Hello
```

Then I say that `b` is another name for `a`:

```
a/b ----------------------Hello
```

Then I change `b`, which changes `a`, because they are two names for the same thing:

```
a/b ----------------------Hi
```

Or perhaps you are thinking that references work like this:

```
a----------------------Hello
```

Then I say that `b` refers to `a`:

```
b -------------- a ----------------------Hello
```

Then I change `b`, which indirectly changes `a`:

```
b -------------- a ----------------------Hi
```

That is, you are expecting to make a reference to a *variable*, instead of a *value*. You *can* do that in C#, like this:

```
void M(ref int x)
{
    x = 1;
}
...
int y = 0;
M(ref y);
```

That means "for the duration of the call to M, x is another name for y". A change to x changes y because they are the same variable.  Notice that the *type* of the variable need not be a reference type.

Answer (score 7):

The line `b = "Hi";` changes which string `b` references.  `a` still references `"Hello"`.

```
string a = "Hello";  // Set a to reference the string "Hello"
string b = a;        // Set b to reference the same string as a
b = "Hi";            // Set b to reference the string "Hi"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the reference b. Not a. The reference itself is copied while the object remains untouched. So b = "Hi" copies a reference to the "Hi" object into b. This does not affect a.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a reference type is the most confusing thing amongst OOP programmers.

Run the below code, and you will be surprised to see the answer:

Create a simple `Book` class with a property called `Name` and write the below code in the `Main` method of the application.

```
Book a = new Book() {Name = "book a"};
Book b = new Book() {Name = "book b"};

Book c = a; //line 3

Book a = b; //Line 4

Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
```

And as no doubt you will expect the answer to be "book b" because of line 4. You think that as **c** is **a** and after that **a** became **b**  which will also make **c** equals **b**.

**Which is not the case**!

Read the balloon anology at [Ballon analogy for Reference type](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html).

Comment: Ok, Replace Book with  string in the example and check if you should have asked the same question or not ?

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that this line (a="Hi") is like making the variable (a) refers to another object,I thought it is changing the object that the variable (a) is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

NO!

What you did, is to create two references ('a','b') to a string "Hello".
With `b = "Hi"` you change 'b' to reference the string "Hi".

'a' will never change this way.