# Why if I send a string as argument in a function it comes back empty?

Tags: c#, .net

With this code:

```
 void SomeMethod(string str)
 {
      string tmpStr = ... Read some value from file ... 

      if( !tmpStr.Empty() ) 
           str = tmpStr;

 }
```

When I call this method with a simple string just created inside the main subroutine:

```
 string localString = "";
 SomeMethod( localString );
```

The value that I get back in `localString` is an empty event when I see in debug that in the method `SomeMethod` the variable `tmpStr` is not empty and the variable `str` in the method is full with chars.

If I change the `SomeMethod` signature to be:

```
SomeMethod(ref string str)
```

I see the right result.

But string is a reference type, so why do I need in this case to send it with `ref`? 
and why I get the result that I expected only when I call:

```
SomeMethod(string str)
```

Comment: This behaviour is expected, strings are immutable by design. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type

Comment: What is `Empty()`? I am assuming some sort of extension method?

Comment: have you tried making the return type a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not just that the string is immutable, but also that while `string` is a reference type, a reference itself is not.  That is, you are passing the `string` by reference, but the reference itself is passed by value.

Thus, for reference types, you can modify the object that is referred to by the parameter (as long as it's modifiable), but you cannot modify what the argument refers to unless you pass it by reference.

So, when you try to change what the `string` variable refers to:

```
str = tmpStr;
```

It changes what `str` refers to locally, but does not affect what the original argument `localString` refers to.

Think of it this way, let's say that the argument `localString` refers to an object at location 1000:

```
localString 
+---------------+                      1000
|      1000     |   -----------------> +---------------+
+---------------+                      | Count: 1      |
                                       | Value: ""     |
                                       +---------------+
```

Then when we pass `localString` to the method, it creates a copy of the reference (as `str`) and updates the reference count...

```
localString 
+---------------+                      1000
|      1000     |   -----------------> +---------------+
+---------------+                      | Count: 2      |
                                       | Value: ""     |
str                                    +---------------+
+---------------+                        ^
|      1000     |   ---------------------+
+---------------+
```

Then, when you assign str to a new string, it modifies the reference `str` but not `localString`:

```
localString
+---------------+                      1000
|      1000     |   -----------------> +---------------+
+---------------+                      | Count: 1      |
                                       | Value: ""     |
str                                    +---------------+
+---------------+                          2500
|      2500     |   ---------------------> +---------------+
+---------------+                          | Count: 1      |
                                           | Value: ...    |
                                           +---------------+
```

So your modification of `str` only changed what `str` refers to, not the original refernce `localString`, if you want to change *that*, then you pass by reference, which means that `str` is a reference back to the original argument (much like a ptr to a ptr):

```
localString
+---------------+                      1000
|      2500     |  ------------------> +---------------+
+---------------+                      | Count: 2      |
        ^                              | Value: ""     |
str     |                              +---------------+
+---------------+       
|               |       
+---------------+
```

Now, when you change `str` it changes the refernce `localString` as well:

```
localString
+---------------+                      1000
|      1000     |  -----+              +---------------+
+---------------+       |              | Count: 0      |
        ^               |              | Value: ""     |
str     |               |              +---------------+
+---------------+       |                  2500
|               |       +----------------> +---------------+
+---------------+                          | Count: 1      |
                                           | Value: ...    |
                                           +---------------+
```

And then, of course, the original string (assuming nothing else refers to it as in this example) can be garbage collected...

So, if you really want to modify the `string` parameter, pass it by `ref` or `out`, or you can return the new mutated version, or store in an instance member (though pass-by-instance-member is a higher order of coupling and can cause other issues...).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use ref all the changes, but assign will take place, it is because str inside of the body of the method is copy of the variable that was passed as argument and it is pointing  to the same instance in the memory so if you call methods or access fields it is on the same instance, but if you assign another instance to str its only start to point to another instance. But as str is only copy of the variable used as the argument the argument would not be changed. If you use ref then no copy is created and same pointer is used.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
string SomeMethod()
{
      string tmpStr = ... Read some value from file ... 

      if( !tmpStr.Empty() ) 
           str = tmpStr;

         return str;
}

string localString = SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Ok , but what about the case of two string as a argument in the 'SomeMethod' ? i don't want to return a class/struct as the return value.

Answer (score 1):

"you cannot change the value of the reference itself; that is, you cannot use the same reference to allocate memory for a new class and have it persist outside the block."

From this site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx#vclrfpassingmethodparameters_example4

So you are only changing the reference inside the block.  There are a two ways around this.
1.  Pass with the ref keyword as you discovered.
2.  As Someone else suggested; change the method to return a string and then declair your new string like this:

```
String localString = SomeMethod();
```