# Why was string defined as a class and not a struct?

Tags: c#, .net, string, class, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, why is String a reference type that behaves like a value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type)

Is is to do with performance or is there some technical reason?

Comment: [This is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type "This is") a very good answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks. My search failed to spot that thread.