# Strings, being reference types behaving like value types

Tags: c#, string, reference, equality

```
        string s1 = "hi";
        string s2 = "hi";
        bool x = (s1 == s2);
        Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse(""+x)); //printed as true and my point of interest
        x = s1.Equals(s2);
        Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse("" + x));//printed as true
        s1 = s2;
        x = (s1 == s2);
        Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse("" + x));//printed as true
        x = s1.Equals(s2);
        Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse("" + x));//printed as true
```

Since `s1==s2` compares references, it shoukd be returned as false. But i get the output as true. I observe this in case of strings alone. When this is done on objects of other classes, it rightly evaluates to false. Why is this exceptional behaviour observed in strings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things going on here.

The first is that the string type overloads the == operator. The reference comparison of the == operator is only the *default* behavior. Any type can overload that operator to get better semantics. If you want to guarantee reference equality, use the [`ReferenceEquals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) method.

The second is something called [interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), which allows two different string variables that have the same value to refer to the same object. Interning means that even without the overloaded == operator, if the "hi" literal is interned for both variables, the == and ReferenceEquals() comparisons could still return true

Comment: interning will never change the result of the `==` operator.  It might change the performance, and it will change the result of `Object.ReferenceEquals`, but not `==`.

Comment: @Servy that's true because the operator is overloaded. I was talking about a hypothetical case where the operator is not overloaded, in which case it would change the result.

Comment: Well, you added that hypothetical after my comment.  Before you just discussed using `operator ==` which, as I said, wouldn't result in any different return values.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Even in the hypothetical case then, the result will be the same right? Because the references point to the same string and is evaluated to true?? Or am I understanding wrong?

Comment: @NithishInpursuitOfhappiness that is mostly right... but there is no guarantee that a given string will be interned.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn And C# supports this probable interning of strings by default?

Comment: @NithishInpursuitOfhappiness By default it will only intern compile time literals.  Since you define `"hi"` as a literal in code twice, they will both point to the same reference, but if you read the strings in from a file, or the console, etc. and they had the same value they would *not* have the same reference (you can turn on such interning if you want though).  They would still be equal when using `operator ==` though, because it compares values.

Answer (score 2):

> Since s1==s2 compares references

That's a false assumption.  You can overload the `==` operator to do whatever you want.

Here is how you can overload it for your own classes, just like `String` does.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public static bool operator ==(Foo first, Foo second)
    {
        return first.Value == second.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but by default is this == operator overloaded for strings?

Comment: @NithishInpursuitOfhappiness Yes, it is, and you can't re-define that behavior for `String`, only for your own classes.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (== and
>   !=) are defined to compare the **values** of string objects, not
>   references (7.9.7 String equality operators). This makes testing for
>   string equality more intuitive.