# Large sized string by ref or value?

Tags: c#

I understand that a string is sent by value even though it is a reference type, but if my string was tens of MB in size and i wanted to send it as an argument.

should i send it by reference or value?

```
private int GetIndexOfNext(string String,int SearchStartIndex,char TargetChar)
```

Or

```
private int GetIndexOfNext(ref string String,int SearchStartIndex,char TargetChar)
```

Comment: To save memory I would send byref as it passes the same string instance without creating new memory allocation as with byval.

Comment: Choose whichever you like. not important. Compiler will **not** pass a copy of it.

Comment: "I understand that a string is sent by value even though it is a reference type" - Excuse me? It is possible that you just express yourself ambigiously but this hints at a fatal misunderstanding. I'll try to state this as clearly as possible: Passing a string around does *not* create a copy of the string object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C#, why is String a reference type that behaves like a value type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type) - you "understand it wrong". Please read the linked topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand that a string is sent by value even though it is a
>   reference type

For strings or other reference types, their **address is passed by value**. It is not the value which gets passed, so for your case it doesn't matter. 
The reason parameter passing involving strings looks different is because **strings are immutable** *(and that when you try to modify string's content)*.

You should see: [Parameter passing in C# by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to pass it as a `string` without the `ref`. The string isn't copied, you've just passed a copy of the reference to the method, rather than a copy of the string.

Answer (score 0):

A small (unsafe) test will show that it's the string address that is passed and not a copy of the string.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String s = "aaa";

        Console.WriteLine(s); // Prints aaa
        F(s);
        Console.WriteLine(s); // Prints aba
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static unsafe void F(String s)
    {
        fixed (char* p = s)
        {
            p[1] = 'b';
        }
    }
```

Comment: All parameters in C# are passed by value by default, in this case the value is itself a reference.  So the object is not passed by reference, rather it is a reference that is passed by value.

Comment: @Servy That's what I mean, I was just using the terminology of his question which might not be a good idea.

Comment: The statement `Strings aren't passed by value` is incorrect, or at the very best, entirely unclear as to its meaning.