# string is value type or reference type?

Tags: c#

I have some confusion about string a reference type or value type, I have two variables of type string, I assign value to first variable and then assigned same variable to second variable, If i change anything on first variable value doesn't get change in second variable, as second variable is also pointing to the same location where first one does?

```
        string string1 = "abc";

        string string2 = string1;

        string1 = "xyz";
```

here string1 is holding value xyz and string2 is abc

Comment: It's a class so it's a reference type. It's also immutable.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel but why both variable are not holding value xyz?

Comment: And it doesn't even matter that it's immutable. Here you are just putting another reference into the variable named `string1`, you are not actually modifying anything.

Comment: Have a look at this SO thread. There's a good discussion there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what's going on:

```
string string1 = "abc";
```

`string1` is a *reference* to the string "abc" which lives on the heap somewhere.

```
string string2 = string1;
```

`string2` is another reference, that just happens to point to the same place in memory as `string1`.  That reference was copied over to `string2` when you used the assignment operator.  You now have two variables that point to the same place in memory.

```
string1 = "xyz";
```

`string1` now points to a *newly created* string that contains "xyz".  `string2` *still* points over to "abc", which is still *reachable* and won't be garbage collected.

In any case, yes; String is a reference type.

Comment: but how come stringbuilder is different from string in this case?

Comment: Because `StringBuilder` is built differently and has different behavior than `string` does.  `StringBuilder` has a different purpose; it contains mutation methods, and allows you to build up a string without incurring the cost of constantly creating new strings.

Comment: `StringBuilder` is optimized for building strings through a bunch of concatenations.  If you did this with `System.String`, it'll have to re-allocate memory over and over again since strings are immutable.

Comment: that's what i wanted to know how string is different from other reference type?

Comment: ..the other point to make is that `string` is a type well understood by the CLR. `StringBuilder` however is just a class that is part of the BCL.

Comment: Yea, `StringBuilder` was written in C#.  You can probably dig up the Mono implementation if you were so inclined.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: .NET implementation is freely available as well. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs#46

Comment: @NitinAggarwal in "how come stringbuilder is different from string in this case" are you asking why `= "foo"` does not have `new` in front of it and creates new string without `new`... ?