# Disposing User Principal Correctly in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code which basically returns the display name for the user. I am utilizing the using keyword to correctly dispose the `PrincipalContext` and the `UserPrincipal`.

My question is that since the result points to `user.DisplayName` would result be pointing to a null or disposed object once the `UserPrincipal` is disposed. I don't think using disposing objects immediately it just marks for disposable and once it needs more memory it disposes the marked objects.

```
private string GetWindowsDisplayName()
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, principal.Identity.Name))
        {
            if (user != null) 
                result = user.DisplayName;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> result points to user.DisplayName

No it doesn't.

The *value* stored in `user.DisplayName` is *copied* to `result`.  What you're returning is just that value, which by then has nothing to do with the `user` object.

You can demonstrate this concept with something like this:

```
var first = "one";
var second = first;
second = "two";
// here, "first" still equals "one"
```

Comment: So strings in .NET are value objects?

Comment: @johndoe: That's actually a pretty interesting question, for which I don't have a canonical enough answer.  In the case of setting values, it certainly *behaves* like a value.  But the `String` class is an object, strings can be `null`, etc.

Comment: @johndoe: Looks like good info can be found here, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type

Comment: @johndoe To elaborate on what David has said, the actual value of the string isn't what gets copied since `string` is a reference type.  Also, because it's a reference type, the string value doesn't actually live inside your user object, the user object merely references it.  Since you capture a copy of that reference via the `result` variable, the string stays alive.

Comment: Additionally, `string` objects are immutable. When you assign a new value to string its a new string object every time.