# Why in C# string type does not work as reference type

Tags: c#

I have below code in C# Console Application:

```
        string a = "1";
        string b = a;
        a = "2";
        Console.WriteLine(b);
```

I heard that in C# the string type works as reference type but in upper code the variable b still shows me 1 and why it does not show me 2 !?

Comment: Where did you hear that, exactly?

Answer (score 9):

Because you are copying the reference. Strings are immutable, so the only way to change the string is to replace it by a different one. And that is what you are doing with `a = "2"`.

After that, there are two strings in memory: `"1"` and `"2"`. `a` points to the latter one but `b` was assigned *a copy* of the reference to `"1"` so that is what you get when you print out `a`.

Answer (score 3):

Stings are immutable and work *like* value types but are *not* (internally they are indeed read only reference types). That's something fundamental and about every doc about .NET is explaining it. Also strings cannot be inherited. It's simple - strings cannot be altered in any way. Every function that seems to alter a string in reality creates a new one.

There is the *StringBuilder* class that can be used for manipulating strings.

For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string

also see: [In C#, why is String a reference type that behaves like a value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type?rq=1)