# Powershell - Normal variables are behaving like reference variables

Tags: powershell

Here is the simple powershell code -

```
$arr = @()
$a = [PSCustomObject]@{
    a = 'a'
    b = 'b'
}
$arr += $a
$b = [PSCustomObject]@{
    a = 'c'
    b = 'd'
}
$arr += $b

$f = $arr | Where-Object {$_.a -eq 'a'}
$f.a = '1'
Write-Host "`$a.a=$($a.a); `$f.a=$($f.a)"
$f.a = '11'
Write-Host "`$a.a=$($a.a); `$f.a=$($f.a)"
```

Output:

```
$a.a=1; $f.a=1
$a.a=11; $f.a=11
```

My problem is - How the changing of `$f` value is also changing the value of `$a` value? I'm not aware of this concept.

And, what can I do to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Usually **objects** are referenced. One of the reasons for this is that the size of an object is undefined as in comparison to a primitive where the size is fixed. This is quiet common for any programming language, see: [Reference (computer science)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `[PSCustomObject]` is a *reference type*, so multiple variables can "point to" (reference) a given instance; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60102611/45375) for more information about *reference types* vs. *value types*.

If you want to create a copy (a shallow clone) of a `[PSCustomObject]` instance, call `.psobject.Copy()`:

```
$f = ($arr | Where-Object {$_.a -eq 'a'}).psobject.Copy()
```