# Powershell 5.1 Write-Output in nested for, ForEach

Tags: powershell

I'm not getting expected output from a script, and I think it has to do with variable scope, but I don't know how to get around it.  I have an input file like this:

```
product,team,goals
Product A,Team A,"in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,25,days,default,manager;in-stock,30,days,default,director;in-stock,45,days,default,VP"
Product B,Team B,"in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,5,days,default,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
Product C,Team B,"in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,5,days,default,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
Product D,Team B,"in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
Product E,Team B,"in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
Product F,Team B,"in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,all,team"
Product G,Team C,"in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,5,days,next,on-call;in-stock,10,days,all,team"
Product H,Team D,"in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,default,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,45,days,default,manager;in-stock,60,days,default,director;in-stock,90,days,default,VP"
```

and Powershell 5.1 script like this:

```
# a Powershell script to validate some goals

### this needs to go in cmdline before running script
### $FormatEnumerationLimit = -1

# set some variables, the files are in a subdirectory called Data
$timestamp = $(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss)
$infile = "Data\Powershell_test_2021_10_07.csv"
$outfile = "Data\Powershell_test_"+$timestamp+".csv"

### current goals
$cfile = Import-Csv $infile

# define the expected goals
$expectedGoals = @{
    0 = "on-call"
    7 = "on-call"
    15 = "next on-call"
    20 = "all team"
    25 = "manager"
    30 = "director"
    45 = "VP"
}
$goalkeys = @($expectedGoals.Keys | Sort)

# do the validation
$dfile = ( $cfile | Select -Property breach,* | ForEach {
    $thisgoal = $_
    $thisgoal.breach = ""
    $agoals = $thisgoal.goals -split ';'
    If ($agoals.Count -lt 7) { $thisgoal.breach = "Goals have < 7 steps"; Write-Output ($thisgoal)}
    For($i=0; $i -lt $agoals.Count; $i++){
        $goalflds = $agoals[$i] -Split ','
        $thiskey = $goalkeys[$i]
        If ($goalflds[2] -ne "days") { $thisgoal.breach = "Goal step $i interval is not in days"; Write-Output ($thisgoal)}
        If ($goalflds[1] -gt $thiskey) { $thisgoal.breach = "Goal step $i is > $thiskey days"; Write-Output ($thisgoal)}
    }
} )
##$flds = @($goal.condition, $goal.interval.time, $goal.interval.timeUnit, $goal.notifyType, $goal.recipient.type)

# export to a csv file
$dfile | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $outfile
```

The script outputs this:

```
"breach","product","team","goals"
"Goal step 3 is > 20 days","Product A","Team A","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,25,days,default,manager;in-stock,30,days,default,director;in-stock,45,days,default,VP"
"Goal step 3 is > 20 days","Product A","Team A","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,25,days,default,manager;in-stock,30,days,default,director;in-stock,45,days,default,VP"
"Goal step 3 is > 20 days","Product A","Team A","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,25,days,default,manager;in-stock,30,days,default,director;in-stock,45,days,default,VP"
"Goal step 3 is > 20 days","Product B","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,5,days,default,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 3 is > 20 days","Product B","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,5,days,default,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 3 is > 20 days","Product B","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,5,days,default,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 3 is > 20 days","Product C","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,5,days,default,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 3 is > 20 days","Product C","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,5,days,default,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 3 is > 20 days","Product C","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,5,days,default,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product D","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product D","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product D","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product D","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product E","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product E","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product E","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product E","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,default,director"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product F","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,all,team"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product F","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,all,team"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product F","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,all,team"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product F","Team B","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,4,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,next,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,30,days,default,manager;in-stock,45,days,all,team"
"Goals have < 7 steps","Product G","Team C","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,5,days,next,on-call;in-stock,10,days,all,team"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product H","Team D","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,default,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,45,days,default,manager;in-stock,60,days,default,director;in-stock,90,days,default,VP"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product H","Team D","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,default,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,45,days,default,manager;in-stock,60,days,default,director;in-stock,90,days,default,VP"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product H","Team D","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,default,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,45,days,default,manager;in-stock,60,days,default,director;in-stock,90,days,default,VP"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product H","Team D","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,default,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,45,days,default,manager;in-stock,60,days,default,director;in-stock,90,days,default,VP"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product H","Team D","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,default,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,45,days,default,manager;in-stock,60,days,default,director;in-stock,90,days,default,VP"
"Goal step 5 is > 30 days","Product H","Team D","in-stock,0,days,default,on-call;in-stock,8,days,default,on-call;in-stock,16,days,next,on-call;in-stock,45,days,default,manager;in-stock,60,days,default,director;in-stock,90,days,default,VP"
```

Sorry if this is a lot of text.

When this runs, I am expecting the breach field to be different for each line that is produced for a particular team and product, but it looks like they all come out as whatever was set last.

How can I fix this??  Thanks for any help!
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with variable scoping, it's a problem of object *lifetime* management.

Objects like `$thisgoal` are passed *by reference*, so `$dfile` doesn't contain 3 separate copies of `$thisgoal`, it really just contains 3 references to the *same* copy - which is why you see the result of the *last* modification of the `breach` property.

You need to create a *new* object everytime you report a new "breach" as output.

`Select-Object` can indeed do that for you, but since there's a 1-to-many relationship between input and output here, you'll want to pipe the input to `ForEach-Object` *first*, at which point we can then call `Select-Object` multiple times (thereby creating multiple *copies*) for each input object if necessary:

```
$dfile = $cfile |ForEach-Object {
    $allGoals = $_.goals -split ';'
    If ($allGoals.Count -lt 7) {
        $_ |Select-Object @{Name='Breach';Expression={"Goals have < 7 steps"}},*
    }
    For ($i = 0; $i -lt $allGoals.Count; $i++) {
        $goalflds = $allGoals[$i] -Split ','
        $thiskey = $goalkeys[$i]
        If ($goalflds[2] -ne "days") {
            $_ |Select-Object @{Name='Breach';Expression={"Goal step $i interval is not in days"}},*
        }
        If ($goalflds[1] -gt $thiskey) { 
            $_ |Select-Object @{Name='Breach';Expression={"Goal step $i is > $thiskey days"}},*
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It led me to the right answer, so close but no cigar.  I added brackets in the Expressions, like Expression={"goals ..."},* and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **you keep updating the *very same object* in your `ForEach-Object` loop**.

When the loop ends, **`$dfile` contains an array whose elements *all reference that one object***, and its **properties contain the values you assigned *last***.

In order **to create *variants* of the original object with different property values, you must create a *copy* every time**, which in the case of the `[pscustomobject]` instances (as output by `Import-Csv` and `Select-Object`) can be achieved with `.psobject.Copy()`

- While it won't be a problem with the input objects in your case, it is important to note that the copies created are *shallow* ones. That is, those property values that happen to contain instances of .NET [*reference types*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) will reference the same instances in the object copies - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60102611/45375) for more information.

A **simplified example**:

```
$modifiedCopies =
  [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 'a' }, [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 'b' } | ForEach-Object {
    # Create, modify and output two copies
    foreach ($i in 1..2) {
      $copy = $_.psobject.Copy() # create a copy
      $copy.prop += $i           # modify it
      $copy                      # output it (Note: no need for Write-Output)
    }
  }
```

Outputting `$modifiedCopies` afterwards yields:

```
prop
----
a1
a2
b1
b2
```

---

**Applied to your code** (apply analogously to the other lines where you update `$thisgoal.breach` and then call `Write-Output ($thisgoal)`):

```
if ($agoals.Count -lt 7) { 
  $copy = $thisgoal.psobject.Copy()      # create a copy
  $copy.breach = "Goals have < 7 steps"  # update the copy
  $copy                                  # output it
}
```

Or, more succinctly, using PowerShell's ability to use assignments as expressions:

```
if ($agoals.Count -lt 7) {
  ($copy = $thisgoal.psobject.Copy()).breach = "Goals have < 7 steps"; $copy
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This was the more simple approach, but I couldn't get it to work.  I kept getting the same results as before.

Comment: @DaveFaught, please see my update, which shows how to apply the technique to your code.