# Cast $PSBoundParameters to [HashTable] to enable .Clone()

Tags: powershell, casting, clone

I have been adding $psBoundParameters to a hash table like this.

```
$seedTaskState = @{
   arguments = $PSBoundParameters
}
```

Later, I need to use those same arguments to call the next function, with one of the values changed. So I used this

```
$nestedTaskParameters = $seedTaskState.arguments
```

and then changed the one value I needed to change. Which... doesn't work because complex types are by reference so I was changing the original bound parameters, which causes all sorts of issues.

I can just initialize `$nestedTaskParameters` as a hash table and loop through the bound parameters and add them, like so.

```
$nestedTaskParameters = @{}
foreach ($key in $seedTaskState.arguments.Keys) {
    $nestedTaskParameters.Add($key, $seedTaskState.arguments.$key)
}
```

And I had thought that this might work, and be more elegant

```
$nestedTaskParameters = $seedTaskState.arguments.Clone()
```

but `.Clone()` is only available with a hashtable, not a bound parameters dictionary.

So I tried casting `$seedTaskState.arguments` to a hash table first, then cloning, like this.

```
$nestedTaskParameters = ([Hashtable]$seedTaskState.arguments).Clone()
```

That seems to work, but is also well outside my comfort zone, so I wonder if there is some sort of gotcha with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If your intent is simply to use the `arguments` for argument [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting),
- it is fine to copy the entries of the [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters) - whose type is derived from a *generic dictionary* ([`` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary-2)) - into a [*hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) ([`[hashtable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable)) by way of a *cast* (which calls the appropriate constructor behind the scenes).

  - Given that the cast invariably creates a *new hashtable object*, it already *is* a clone, so there's no need to call `.Clone()` on it.

Splatting works with any dictionary-like type that implements the [`` System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary-2) .NET interface or its non-generic counterpart, [`System.Collections.IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary).

**Caveat**:

- The resulting hashtable is a collection of entries that is *separate* from `$PSBoundParameters`, i.e. you can add or remove entries or assign new values to its entries independently, without affecting `$PSBoundParameters`.
- However, **if `$PSBoundParameters` entry values happen to be instances of [.NET *reference types*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), modifying these values from either dictionary affects *both* dictionaries**, because the corresponding entries in both dictionaries "point to" (reference) the very same object instance. That is, what the `[hashtable]` constructor created were what are called ***shallow* copies of the entries in `$PSBoundParameters`**, and the same would apply to calling `.Clone()` on an existing hashtable.

  - If you need to avoid that, you'll have to manually create *deep* copies of such values, which may be nontrivial; to determine whether a given value is an instance of .NET reference type, use `-not $someValue.GetType().IsValueType`
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60102611/45375) for more information.

```sh
# Sample function.
function Foo {

  param(
    $bar,
    $baz
  )
  
  # Effectively copy the entries from $PSBoundParameters into a 
  # new hashtable.
  $hashtable = [hashtable] $PSBoundParameters

  # Add new entries to the hashtable.
  $hashtable.new1 = 'stuff1'
  $hashtable.new2 = 'stuff2'
  # Remove one.
  $hashtable.Remove('bar')

  # Modify the instance of the .NET reference type stored in the entry
  # with key 'baz'.
  # THIS AFFECTS THE ORIGINAL ENTRY IN $PSBoundParameters TOO.
  $hashtable.baz.prop = 2

  # Output the two dictionaries.
  '-- $PSBoundParameters'
  $PSBoundParameters
  "`n-- hashtable`n"
  $hashtable

}

# Call the function with an instance of a value type and a reference type.
Foo 42 ([pscustomobject] @{ prop = 1 })
```

The above yields the following, which shows that directly modifying the  entry whose value is an instance of a .NET reference type affected *both* dictionaries, while adding and removing entries did not:

```
-- $PSBoundParameters

Key      Value
---      -----
bar         42
baz  @{prop=2}

-- hashtable

new2    stuff2
new1    stuff1
baz  @{prop=2}
```