# Although String is a reference type why "==" operator behave correctly in 2 string?

Tags: c#, .net

We know String is a reference type and immutable and so reasonable to be that. It means the address of a string store in Stack and its content store in Heap section memory. On the other hand, we know "==" Operation just compares stack value. So for example we have the following code that compares two Objects as we expect in theory.

And in Microsoft [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators) we have this:

> By default, two non-record reference-type operands are equal if they refer to the same object:

```
   public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new MyClass(1);
        var b = new MyClass(1);
        var c = a;
        Console.WriteLine(a == b);  // output: False
        Console.WriteLine(a == c);  // output: True
    }
```

But my question is why in a string that is reference type "==" operation behaves like value-type! I just curious about technical reason and how Dotnet act for it, not just concept (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type) )

```
string t1 = "test";
string t2 = "test";
bool result = t1 == t2; // output: True
```

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings#linguistic-comparisons is useful to do string comparison the right way.

Comment: In essence, because `System.String` overrides the `==` operator. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,705

Comment: See also [String.Equality(String, String) Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.op_equality?view=net-5.0). Note that the new C# 9.0 record types do this as well, to provide value comparison for a reference type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `string` type just implements custom equality comparision operators. Any class can do that and make `==` (and other equality operators) behave "like value-type". For example, that's what is done for new "record" types which are reference types but behave "like" value types.

However, there is one more thing. In your example code:

```
string t1 = "test";
string t2 = "test";
bool result = t1 == t2; // output: True
```

Even if you check if both strings actually refer to the same object, it will still return true:

```
bool result = Object.ReferenceEquals(t1, t2); // output: True
```

That's because they ARE actually refer to the same object, because of string interning. There is a global pool of strings in the program, in which one can place a string or if string is already there - get a reference to that same string (via `String.Intern` call). All string literals declared in your program automatically are placed there. That means both `t1` and `t2` refer to the same string object in that intern pool.

If you do something like:

```
string t1 = "test";
string t2 = new StringBuilder().Append("test").ToString();
bool result = Object.ReferenceEquals(t1, t2);
```

Then `t2` is no longer automatically interned and comparision will return false (but of course, comparision with `==` will still return true).